# CSS Wrong on Chrome and IE, Works on Firefox

Tags: html, css

Please look at the address under the storefront picture on the left on this page:
http://walkerloden.com/about.html

It's right under the picture when I use Firefox, but when I use IE or Chrome it's towards the middle of the page. Any ideas why?

Comment: Please post your **relevant** code here.

Comment: P.S. don't use `br`s to force margin and don't use tables for layouting.

Comment: That's a horrible way to set that up by the way, tons of BR and a table. You need some div structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overall design is pretty backwards.  But to work with what you have you could add a clear:left to that table and it would do the trick.

Comment: Cancelling my answer, which was the same. Especially +1 for "design is pretty backwards".  The image and the caption that goes with it could just be grouped together within a `<div>`.  Using a load of `<br>` tags to create vertical whitespace is bad; use top & bottom margins or padding.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I just "inherited" the site. Do you mean its "backwards" in appearance or code?

Answer (score 0):

to fix your problem if you add two more `<br>` it will work on both.

This is not the best way to deal with that problem but it will fixe it (eventually you'll need to position your text under the image inside a div and not use `<br>`)

Answer (score 0):

add two more `<br>` and then it works fine

Comment: Don't use `<br>` -- use margins and padding.  `<br>` exists to allow you to break a line of text in a specific place; CSS is the way to create empty space between elements.